# How do you include a record that has already been defined in another .avdl file?

Tags: java, avro

I have the following .avdl file that I'm trying to compile:

```
@namespace("com.test.foo.bar")
protocol PairStore {

    /* This is already defined in another namespace - "com.test.foo.nan" */
    record Pair {
        string item1;
        string item2;
    }

    record Registration {
        Pair inputPair;
        Pair outputPair;
        string indexURI;
    }
}
```

So the question is how do I reference the `Pair` that's been defined in `com.test.foo.nan` when I'm creating `PairStore` and `Registration` in `com.test.foo.bar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through the Avro docs I finally found an example that contained the solution. Specifically, [this example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/avro/trunk/lang/java/compiler/src/test/idl/input/namespaces.avdl).

```
@namespace("com.test.foo")
protocol PairStore {

    /** Still need to define this record, but define it in the existing namespace. */
    @namespace("com.test.bar")
    record Pair {
        string item1;
        string item2;
    }

    record Registration {
        /** And this is how you refer to that record. */
        com.test.bar.Pair inputPair;
        com.test.bar.Pair outputPair;
        string indexURI;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to import the record from the other avdl file like so:

```
@namespace("com.test.foo")
    protocol PairStore {

    /** No need to define the record again, 
        just import the file that has Pair defined*/
    import idl "bar.avdl";

    record Registration {
        /** And this is how you refer to that record. */
        com.test.bar.Pair inputPair;
        com.test.bar.Pair outputPair;
        string indexURI;
    }
}
```